# Source on the life of Shlomo Hamelech

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, midrash, king-solomon

There are many Gemoras, Mirashim and Mifarshim explaining what Shlomo did or did not do wrong. Can anyone recommend a Sefer, dissertation or book on the life of King Shlomo which gives perspective on the opinions seen in the different midrashim?

Ideally, I would like one source rather than seeing many different midrashim from different places. I want more of a synthesis approach that can contrast and compare the different Gemoras and Midrashim we have on Shlomo Hamelech.
Thank you!

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/From_David_to_Destruction%2C_The_Rise_and_Fall_of_Shlomo_HaMelech%2C_The_Conversion_of_Shlomo_HaMelech's_Wives.1?lang=bi

Answer (score 5):

I haven't seen a biography, but I would recommend Artscroll's brilliant [Ishei HaTanach](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899060255.html) by Yishai Chasidah which spends considerable time (fifteen and a half pages) on Shlomo Hamelech and is fully sourced.

It explores the following areas:

- Chronology
- Personality
- King
- Judge
- Wisdom
- Wealth
- Torah study
- The Temple
- The Throne
- Writings
- Wives
- Shortcomings
- Banished
- Anecdotes

Comment: Thank you! I will have to look into it. I like the seferia link

Answer (score 2):

Also not a biography, but the sefer Nachalas Shimon by R' Shimon Krasner has brilliant breakdowns of the actions of figures in Neviim Rishonim, as seen through Chazal up until the more recent authorities. Each topic gets its own chapter.